# Finding $P(C)$ if $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive, given $P(A \cap B)$, $P(A \cup B)$,$ P(A)$, $P(B)$, using Additive Principle

Tags: probability

**Additive Principle:**

> $P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)−P(A \cap B)$

I found the following numbers, and verified that they are indeed correct:

$P(A) = 0.2$,
$P(B) = 0.3$,
$P(A \cup B) = 0.5$,
$P(A \cap B) = 0$(Mutually exclusive),
$P(C) = ?$

The thing is, there is no $P(C)$ in the additive principle, I found all of these values, but I'm not sure how I can fit $P(C)$ into the principle, if $P(C)$ doesn't exist in the first place. If someone can just push me in the direction that'd be awesome!

## Entire question BELOW.

> A sample space contains only three simple events: A, B, and C. If P(A) = 0.2 and P(B) = 0.3 find:
>
> P(A and B) if A and B are mutually exclusive
>
> P(A or B) if a and B are mutually exclusive
>
> P(C) if A and B are mutually exclusive

Comment: It looks correct, if indeed P(A∩B)=0

Comment: @CAGT I don't follow, I'm being asked to calculate the unknown value for P(C), the problem is in the additive principle, there is only P(A) and P(B), no P(C), so I'm not sure how you would calculate that, the answer says 0.5, but I'm not sure how they got that? Also I apologize, I'm not familiar with properly getting the write text format for equations and proper symbols :)

Comment: I guess P(C) is the result for mutually exclusive events.  So it should read P(C)=P(A∪B)=P(A)+P(B)−P(A∩B), if you still don't feel comfortable, then if P(C) is a third event, you need different formulas.

Comment: For completeness sake, you should post the entire problem so everyone can agree on an answer. Also, formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @probablyme Updated OP with full question taken word for word from the textbook.

Comment: If A, B and C are mutually exclusive, then P(C) = 1 - P(A) - P(B).

Comment: If the space contains *only* three simple events: $\mathsf P(A\cup B\cup C) = 1$

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to go with: You are not given enough information about C to find more than a lower bound on its probability

Comment: Also, this "additive principle" works for $n$ events. For 3, it is $P(A\cup B\cup C) = P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(AB)-P(BC)-P(AC)+P(ABC).$ See [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#In_probability).